# How can I implement deconvolution layer for a CNN in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, convolution, deconvolution

I try to implement Deconvolution layer for a Convolution Network. What I mean by deconvolution is that suppose I have `3x227x227` input image to a layer with filters in size `3x11x11` and stride 4. Hence the resulting feature map has size `55x55`. What I try to do is to apply the reverse operation where I project `55x55` feature map to again `3x227x227` image. Basically each value on `55x55` feature map is weighted by `3x11x11` filters and projected to image space and overlapping regions due to stride is averaged.

I tried to implement it in numpy without any success. I found the solution with a brute-force nested for loops but it is damn slow. How can I implement it in numpy efficiently? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Share the inefficient loopy code you got?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699513/how-to-update-the-weights-of-a-deconvolutional-layer), a deconvolution is just a convolutional layer, but with a particular choice of padding, stride and filter size.

For example, if your current image size is `55x55`, you can apply a convolution with `padding=20`, `stride=1` and `filter=[21x21]` to obtain a `75x75` image, then `95x95` and so on. (I'm not saying this choice of numbers gives the desired *quality* of the output image, just the size. Actually, I think downsampling from `227x227` to `55x55` and then upsampling back to `227x227` is too aggressive, but you are free to try any architecture).

Here's the implementation of a forward pass for any stride and padding. It does [im2col transformation](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/07/16/convnet-conv-layer/), but using `stride_tricks` from numpy. It's not as optimized as modern GPU implementations, but definitely faster than [4 inner loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699513/how-to-update-the-weights-of-a-deconvolutional-layer/46510786#46510786):

```
import numpy as np

def conv_forward(x, w, b, stride, pad):
  N, C, H, W = x.shape
  F, _, HH, WW = w.shape

  # Check dimensions
  assert (W + 2 * pad - WW) % stride == 0, 'width does not work'
  assert (H + 2 * pad - HH) % stride == 0, 'height does not work'

  # Pad the input
  p = pad
  x_padded = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (p, p), (p, p)), mode='constant')

  # Figure out output dimensions
  H += 2 * pad
  W += 2 * pad
  out_h = (H - HH) / stride + 1
  out_w = (W - WW) / stride + 1

  # Perform an im2col operation by picking clever strides
  shape = (C, HH, WW, N, out_h, out_w)
  strides = (H * W, W, 1, C * H * W, stride * W, stride)
  strides = x.itemsize * np.array(strides)
  x_stride = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x_padded,
                                             shape=shape, strides=strides)
  x_cols = np.ascontiguousarray(x_stride)
  x_cols.shape = (C * HH * WW, N * out_h * out_w)

  # Now all our convolutions are a big matrix multiply
  res = w.reshape(F, -1).dot(x_cols) + b.reshape(-1, 1)

  # Reshape the output
  res.shape = (F, N, out_h, out_w)
  out = res.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)
  out = np.ascontiguousarray(out)
  return out
```

Comment: I’ve a question regarding the transpose conv layer and you seem to have knowledge about it. May I be able to contact you in a way or should I post my question here and share the link as commend here?